# How to optimize startup time for android application with Ads

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, startup

I created a simple mobile app that plays a single music track ( as a practice ) , and I have added one banner Ad in the onCreate Method as seen the code snippets below .

However , the startup time has increased several seconds more than before which is really annoying for a user experience . Is there a way to add the Ads to the app and reduce the startup time for the app .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // Adding Banner Add
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView1);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    m1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.short_sound);


    Button playSong = findViewById(R.id.playSong);
    Button stopSong = findViewById(R.id.stopSong);
    Button reset = findViewById(R.id.reset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider loading the ad on a separate thread:

```
new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus)
            {
            }
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }
}.run();
```

Then load the result on to View on the main thread like so:

```
runOnUiThread(...set component to ui...);
```

You must make sure that the ad view is initialized with some placeholder display first.